Generate bitly to SMS campaign
I need to shorten the Data extension URL to bitly and preview the same in SMS,
I'm currently using the below code for the same and have issues.
Can anyone help me out here? (I'm trying to preview in the content builder)
Errors I got,

An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call. See inner exception for details.
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

%%[

SET @endpoint = "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten"
SET @contentType = "application/json"
SET @bitlyToken = "e86b8c63367be34534280443b67716044c646add"
SET @additionalHeaderName = "Authorization"
SET @LoginURL = [LoginURL]
SET @additionalHeaderValue = CONCAT("Bearer ", @bitlyToken)

SET @payload = CONCAT('{"group_guid":"BITLYgroupIDhere","domain":"bit.ly","long_Url":"',@LoginURL,'"}')

SET @Request = HTTPPost(@endpoint, @contentType, @payload, @Response, @additionalHeaderName, @additionalHeaderValue)

]%%
{{.datasource response type=variable source=@response}}
   {{.data}}
      {"target":"@response"}
   {{/data}}
  %%[
   VAR @shortLink
   SET @shortLink = TreatAsContent('{{link}}')
  ]%%
{{/datasource}}
Hi There! Please login to your account by clicking on the link - %%=v(@shortLink)=%%


Maybe the group guid is not with the correct value. It works when I try to remove the group_guid attribute in the payload. So if you don't really need that attribute, you can remove it.
Try it yourself with this code:
%%[
SET @endpoint = "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten"
SET @contentType = "application/json"
SET @bitlyToken = "e86b8c63367be34534280443b67716044c646add"
SET @additionalHeaderName = "Authorization"
SET @LoginURL = "https://example.com/"
SET @additionalHeaderValue = CONCAT("Bearer ", @bitlyToken)

SET @payload = Concat('{ "domain": "bit.ly", "long_url": "', @LoginURL, '"}')

SET @Request = HTTPPost(@endpoint, @contentType, @payload, @Response, @additionalHeaderName, @additionalHeaderValue)

]%%
{{.datasource response type=variable source=@response}}
   {{.data}}
      {"target":"@response"}
   {{/data}}
  %%[
   VAR @shortLink
   SET @shortLink = TreatAsContent('{{link}}')
  ]%%
{{/datasource}}
Hi There! Please login to your account by clicking on the link - %%=v(@shortLink)=%%

